# Convert Maven Build type from jar to war

Tags: java, spring, maven

I have a maven application that have multiple modules. This is the project architecture. 
[image]

In this project digitalwallet is my main application. following is digitalwallet-api pom.xml

```js
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
 <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
 <packaging>jar</packaging>
 <parent>
  <groupId>com.mobios</groupId>
  <artifactId>digitalwallet</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
 </parent>
```

**And i edited  jar to war**
The war is generated but when i call the api those are not initialized. So i am getting **HTTP Status 404 – Not Found**

Following is my main class

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class)
    public class MainApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MainApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

The executable jar is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Is your digitalwallet working as a Parent Pom. If yes it should be

```
 <packaging>pom</packaging>
```

else if it your web project

```
 <packaging>war</packaging>
```

should be fine.

If yours is a Spring Boot application you would probably need this maven-plugin:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: My parent project packaging is <packaging>pom</packaging> and everything there as you said

Comment: I have everything as you said.@Irshaad

Answer (score 0):

There is a maven plugin called [maven-war-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/war-mojo.html) which may be useful for you.

> The WAR Plugin is responsible for collecting all artifact dependencies, classes and resources of the web application and packaging them into a web application archive.

[Maven Repository](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-war-plugin):

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-war-plugin -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: if i use this how this work. Is there any configuration needed in pom

Comment: You can invoke this plugin as part of the `package` phase.

Comment: Documentation here: 
https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/usage.html